# Equivalent of strcmp() in Java for comparing byte arrays

Tags: java, android

I use a byte array to fit 1024 bytes. The problem is, at separate times in my code I need to only use SOME of those bits. In C, I have used...

```
byte buff[] = read();
strcmp( buff, "CMD\r\n" );
```

This would ignore all later bytes in the array, and only compare the first 5 bytes. Is there an easy way to do this in Java?

Comment: It's important to understand that in Java, `char` and `byte` are very different types (different numbers of bits, amongst other things).

Comment: would it be possible for me to implement a for loop and just compare byte to char? How would I need to convert the char to match the byte? use its ascii value?

Comment: @ JuiCe: You'd use the relevant [`Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) to do a character-to-byte (or byte-to-character) conversion. One of the `Charset` implementations you can use is `"US-ASCII"`, but most text these days is *not* written in that charset. (To be fair, though, I believe all five of the characters you've quoted are the same in all charsets that have them.)

Comment: String temp = new String(buff);
temp.compareTo("CMD\r\n");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compare an array of bytes with [Arrays.equals( byte[], byte[] )](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28byte%5B%5D,%20byte%5B%5D%29).

```
byte[] buff = ...;
boolean isEqual = Arrays.equals( buff, 
                    "CMD\r\n".getBytes( Charset.forName( "US-ASCII" )));
```

**EDIT**: I missed that your byte array is 1024 bytes.

One option is to compare a slice of the byte array:

```
byte[] buff = ...;
final byte[] CMD_BYTES = "CMD\r\n".getBytes( Charset.forName( "US-ASCII" ));
boolean isEqual = Arrays.equals( Arrays.copyOf( buff, CND_BYTES.length()),
                    CMD_BYTES );
```

Another option is to convert the byte array up to a String, allowing an expression similar to C++.

```
byte[] buff = ...;
int buffLen = ...;
String command = new String( buff, 0, buffLen, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
int cmp = command.compareTo( "CMD\r\n");
```

Comment: *"You can compare an array of bytes with `Arrays.equals( byte[], byte[] )`."* You can, but it doesn't help the OP with comparing a `byte[1024]` with a `String` (or the `char[5]` he could readily convert it to, **or** the `byte[n]` he could convert **that** to via one of the `Charset` implementations).

Comment: Re your edit: Arrays of different lengths are not equal. It's the first thing that gets checked.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer: Took the liberty of fixing a couple of errors I could see in the update.

Answer (score 3):

Well it's trivial to write it yourself:

```
public static boolean truncatedEquals(byte[] x, byte[] y) {
    int upperBound = Math.min(x.length, y.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < upperBound; i++) {
        if (x[i] != y[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I don't believe there's anything built into Java for this.

Note that I've made the input two `byte[]` - bytes and strings are very different, and should be treated differently.

Comment: I don't think you could use `Arrays.asList`, at least not if you want to pass in `buff`. It wouldn't auto box the individual bytes, so you'd have a List with a single `byte[]` element, which is next to useless for comparison.

Comment: @yshavit: Ah, had forgotten that `Arrays.asList` didn't work with primitives. Will remove.